# Prove $W \cap W^\perp =\{\vec{0}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $W^\perp = \overline{W} =
>  \{v \cdot w = 0, \forall w \in W\}$
>
> Prove $W \cap W^\perp = \{\vec{0}\}$.

How do I fully prove this intersection is $\vec{0}$? I showed $\vec{0}$ is in $W$, $\overline{W}$, since they are both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, thus $\vec{0}$ is a subset of $W \cap \overline{W}$  which is also a subset of $\vec{0}$.

Then I must show $u = \vec{0}$ to complete.

I have let $u$ be an element of  $W \cap \overline{W}$  which implies $u$ is an element of the zero vector (because they are subsets of each other). But does this show $u$ must be equal to $\vec{0}$? If not, how do I show that part?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 8):

Take ${\bf u} \in W \cap W^\perp$. Then $\langle {\bf u},{\bf u}\rangle = 0$ (why?). So $\bf u = 0$, because $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: ok, so how exactly do I take the u (element of) the interesction? I think I know how to take write u is an element of w, and w(perp) sepearately, but no idea what to do with the intersection of them mathematically.

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Bearing in mind that ${\bf u} \in W$, what is the *definition* of $\bf u$ being in $W^\perp$?

Comment: does it mean that u dot any w = 0?

Comment: Yes, and you can take a very particular $\bf w$. Which one?

Comment: 0? ... because 0 vector dot 0 vector = 0?

Comment: And that's the *only* vector for what this happens.

Comment: i see how that makes w = 0, but how exactly does 0 being the only w make u = 0?

Comment: I don't think you've got the concept of $W^\perp$ fully... it means that everytime you get a vector in $W$, and a vector in $W^\perp$, they are orthogonal. Take ${\bf u} \in W$, and take ${\bf u}\in W^\perp$ (the same $\bf u$!!!). Then $\langle {\bf u},{\bf u} \rangle = 0$, and the result follows by what I said earlier.

Comment: ok i understand that except for the bracket notation you used at the end. does that read u dot u = 0? or something else..

Comment: $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the dot product you're used to. It is just another notation (more used, for general abstract vector spaces)

Comment: ok now i see how if u in W and u in W(hat) then u dot u = 0. i'm just having a slight bit of trouble seeing how the result follows that u = 0 vector? how can i prove this mathematically?

Comment: By **definition** of $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$, we have that: $$\langle {\bf u},{\bf u}\rangle = 0 \iff {\bf u} = {\bf 0}.$$

Comment: how could I prove that result without that notation... or if im understanding correctly, how does the definition of the dot product imply u dot u implies u = 0 vector?

Comment: Copy my argument writing ${\bf u}\cdot {\bf u}$ instead of $\langle {\bf u},{\bf u}\rangle$, if that's bothering you so much..

Comment: but WHY does this imply u = 0?

Comment: It is a **definition**, we don't argue with that, it's a given. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), in "positive-definiteness"

Answer (score 2):

Let's say there did exist an element $(a\not = \vec{0}) \in W\cap W^\perp$. Then $a \cdot a \not = 0$ (any nonzero vector dotted with itself does not equal $0$), contradicting the fact that $a \in W$ and $a \in W^\perp$ (since we know that for any vector $w\in W$ and $w' \in W^\perp, w\cdot w' = 0$) . Thus, $a$ must be equal to $\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $W ∩ W^{⊥} = {0}$

If we say u represents a vector that is present in both $W$ and $W^{⊥}$,

then $u \cdot u = 0$, or in other words $u^2 = 0$.

If we take the square root of both sides, we see that $u = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please format your text using LaTeX.